# Irish place names pronounced incorrectly

Tags: actions-on-google

The speech synthesizer knows that Galway is pronouced 'gol-way' but has no understanding of anglicized versions of other town names such as Portlaoise which it should pronounce 'port-leash' or Thurles 'fur-less'.

Is there a way to correct the default pronunciation in JSON?

Comment: Could you file a support request so we can follow up with you: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Google should be doing a better job about some of the places, as Leon indicated in the comment, sometimes there will be cases where the audio just doesn't match the text and you want to coerce it yourself.

In these cases, you can use the [SSML](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) `<sub>` tag in your response. It takes an `alias` parameter which contains how you would like it pronounced, while the body of the tag would contain the displayable text.

I haven't tested it (and I'm not sure I'd know how it should sound, even if I did), but SSML like the following might be what you're looking for:

```
<speak>
  Welcome to <sub alias="furless">Thurles</sub>.
</speak>
```

If you're using the node.js library from Google, it should detect this as SSML and set parameters in the response accordingly. If you're writing the JSON yourself, you will need to send it in the `ssml` field instead of the `textToSpeech` field in your [SimpleResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#SimpleResponse).